# Firebase : Devices below Lollipop is not receiving notification from my local server

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am following [androidhive's tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/). I am having weird problem if I try sending notification from console everything is fine. But if I try sending notification from web app devices below lollipop is not receiving any notification. What might be the possible problem

Answer (score 0):

This is first time I hearing this type of issue and have you tested with other device other than your development devices. If a device is registered with the gms then it should receive the message. Try to clear the cache data of your app might be helpful.